# Can't install unrar to open .rar files: Connecting to www.rarlab.com (www.rarlab.com)|5.135.104.98|:80... connected

Tags: rar

I want to open .rar file with unrar in Ubuntu 17.04.

So i tried these  commands from this [Link](https://www.wikihow.com/Unrar-Files-in-Linux):

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
cd /tmp
wget http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-3.9.1.tar.gz
```

The output of the 3rd command:

```
--2017-11-01 20:02:38--  http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-3.9.1.tar.gz
Resolving www.rarlab.com (www.rarlab.com)... 5.135.104.98
Connecting to www.rarlab.com (www.rarlab.com)|5.135.104.98|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2017-11-01 20:02:46--  (try: 2)  http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-3.9.1.tar.gz
Connecting to www.rarlab.com (www.rarlab.com)|5.135.104.98|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2017-11-01 20:02:55--  (try: 3)  http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-3.9.1.tar.gz
Connecting to www.rarlab.com (www.rarlab.com)|5.135.104.98|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

^C
```

Until i press `CTRL`+`C`.
What should i do?

The output of `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8`:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=569 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=569 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=570 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=572 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=573 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=573 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=575 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=278 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=278 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=278 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=281 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=198 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, +9 duplicates, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 198.663/443.238/575.646/153.742 ms
```

Comment: What is the output if you `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install unrar` works for me. It was even already installed. What didn't work about it for you?

Comment: @Dan for me it seems like a problem with the connection to the Internet, `wget` that link works for me, but redirects to using https://

Comment: I installed it like this way last time(before i reinstall the ubuntu) I have no idea why can't install it this time @Dan

Comment: That (DUP!) means Duplicate and Damaged Packets, so i guess you check if you could download that file via browser and recheck your settings. If you're not on a server install that is.

Comment: wget didn't work... because of my ping or network connection? if it's about my connection, why can i download files with 700KB/S or Sometimes with 1.5MB/s @Videonauth .... or it's about something else?

Comment: I just judge by what I have seen so far, I tried the wget on my machine and it was fine downloading the file without a hitch and a ping to Googles DNS server should not return (DUP!) at the end and neither take so long. Thus why I made my above comments. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13254/166226 for reference.

Comment: so it can hamefull for my hardware?? That's why my ssd failed last time?(i  bought a new one about 2 week ago!) it'll fail again?if i ignore these problem? :-/  @Videonauth

Comment: No it won't hurt your hardware. It only hurts your ability to get files from the web, and you should simply investigate to get a better user experience overall. :) It even can be due to an outage on your ISP side that this happens (yes they can mess up too, they're only human).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already installed `unrar` when you ran the `apt` command.

Just run it from the terminal (see `man unrar`):

```
unrar e myrar.rar
```

If you want to *make* `rar` files, install the `rar` package:

```
sudo apt install rar
```

Comment: yeah you are right, it's already installed :-/ ... and it works... anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can install UnRAR with a .deb installer (UnRAR Debian amd64) 
https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm